# Create a hierarchy tree

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I would like to follow the format of this hierarchy: [MeSH Qualifier Hierarchies](https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/subhierarchy.html)

**INPUT XML**

```
<QualifierRecordSet LanguageCode="eng">
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>chemistry</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y03</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>agonists</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y03.010</TreeNumber>
    <TreeNumber>Y07.030</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>analogs &amp; derivatives</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y03.020</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>antagonists &amp; inhibitors</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y03.030</TreeNumber>
    <TreeNumber>Y07.040</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>chemical synthesis</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y03.040</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>pharmacology</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y07</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>poisoning</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y07.020.010</TreeNumber>
    <TreeNumber>Y10.040</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>pharmacokinetics</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y07.070</TreeNumber>
    <TreeNumber>Y08.040.060</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>toxicity</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y07.020.020</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>contraindications</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y07.050</TreeNumber>
    <TreeNumber>Y10.030</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>administration &amp; dosage</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y07.010</TreeNumber>
    <TreeNumber>Y10.010</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
  <QualifierRecord>
    <String>adverse effects</String>
    <TreeNumber>Y07.020</TreeNumber>
    <TreeNumber>Y10.020</TreeNumber>
  </QualifierRecord>
</QualifierRecordSet>
```

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="QualifierRecord" use="substring(TreeNumber, 1, string-length(TreeNumber) - 4)" />

<xsl:template match="QualifierRecordSet">
    <node id="MeSH" label="NIH MeSH Qualifiers">
        <isComposedBy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="QualifierRecord[not(contains(TreeNumber, '.'))]"/>
        </isComposedBy>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="QualifierRecord">
    <node id="{TreeNumber}" label="{String}">
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('child', TreeNumber)" />
        <xsl:if test="$children">
            <isComposedBy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$children"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </xsl:if>
    </node>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My target output should look like this:

```
<node id="MeSH" label="NIH MeSH Qualifiers">
  <isComposedBy>
    <node id="Y03" label="chemistry">
        <isComposedBy>
            <node id="Y03.020" label="analogs &amp; derivatives"/>
            <node id="Y03.030" label="antagonists &amp; inhibitors"/>
            <node id="Y03.040" label="chemical synthesis"/>
            <node id="Y03.010" label="agonists"/>
        </isComposedBy>
    </node>
    <node id="Y07" label="pharmacology">
        <isComposedBy>
            <node id="Y07.010" label="administration &amp; dosage"/>
            <node id="Y07.020" label="adverse effects">
                <isComposedBy>
                    <node id="Y07.020.010" label="poisoning"/>
                    <node id="Y07.020.020" label="toxicity"/>
                </isComposedBy>
            </node>
            <node id="Y07.030" label="agonists"/>
            <node id="Y07.040" label="antagonists &amp; inhibitors"/>
            <node id="Y07.050" label="contraindications"/>
            <node id="Y07.070" label="pharmacokinetics"/>
        </isComposedBy>
    </node>
  </isComposedBy>
</node>
```

My problem now is that some terms like `agonists` and `antagonists &amp; inhibitors` have more than one `TreeNumber` in my input example. In this case, the terms I mentioned appeared in the `pharmacology` and `chemistry` tree. Below is my output xml in which the terms `agonists` and `antagonists &amp; inhibitors` only appeared in the `chemistry` portion. I want to appear them both based on their `TreeNumber`. I based my XSLT by the way from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31373764/1919069 on how to create a hierarchy based on its `TreeNumber`.

```
<node id="MeSH" label="NIH MeSH Qualifiers">
  <isComposedBy>
    <node id="Y03" label="chemistry">
        <isComposedBy>
            <node id="Y03.010" label="agonists"/>
            <node id="Y03.020" label="analogs &amp; derivatives"/>
            <node id="Y03.030" label="antagonists &amp; inhibitors"/>
            <node id="Y03.040" label="chemical synthesis"/>
        </isComposedBy>
    </node>
    <node id="Y07" label="pharmacology">
        <isComposedBy>
            <node id="Y07.070" label="pharmacokinetics"/>
            <node id="Y07.050" label="contraindications"/>
            <node id="Y07.010" label="administration &amp; dosage"/>
            <node id="Y07.020" label="adverse effects">
                <isComposedBy>
                    <node id="Y07.020.010" label="poisoning"/>
                    <node id="Y07.020.020" label="toxicity"/>
                </isComposedBy>
            </node>
        </isComposedBy>
    </node>
  </isComposedBy>
</node>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a bit awkward to do in XSLT 1.0, where the *key* of a node cannot contain more than one *string* (though it *can* contain several *nodes*). Still, it's not too difficult to work around the limitation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="child" match="TreeNumber" use="substring(., 1, string-length() - 4)" />

<xsl:template match="QualifierRecordSet">
    <node id="MeSH" label="NIH MeSH Qualifiers">
        <isComposedBy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="QualifierRecord[not(contains(TreeNumber, '.'))]"/>
        </isComposedBy>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="QualifierRecord">
    <node id="{TreeNumber}" label="{String}">
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('child', TreeNumber)" />
        <xsl:if test="$children">
            <isComposedBy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$children"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </xsl:if>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TreeNumber">
    <node id="{.}" label="{../String}">
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('child', .)" />
        <xsl:if test="$children">
            <isComposedBy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$children"/>
            </isComposedBy>
        </xsl:if>
    </node>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```